# Grab array components from string created from text file using Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, csv, nsmutablearray

I have a text file in the following format (abbreviated below):

```
Title";"SeriesID";"ChannelName
Title1";"00000001";"Channel1
Title2";"00000002";"Channel2
Title3";"00000003";"Channel3
...
Title99999999";"99999999";"Channel99999999
```

I have loaded this text file as a resource in Xcode 7 and am parsing it as follows:

```
class TVSeriesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var seriesDict = [String:String]()
    var seriesArray = NSMutableArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("series", ofType: "txt")

        let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        if filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(path!) {

            do {

                let fullText = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

                let readings = fullText.componentsSeparatedByString("\n") as [String]

                for i in 1..<readings.count {

                    let seriesData = readings[i].componentsSeparatedByString("\";\"")

                    seriesDict["Title"] = "\(seriesData[0])"
                    seriesDict["SeriesID"] = "\(seriesData[1])"
                    seriesDict["ChannelName"] = "\(seriesData[2])"

                    seriesArray.addObject(seriesDict)

                }

                for element in seriesArray {

                    print(element)

                }

            } catch let error as NSError {

                print("Error: \(error)")

            }

        }

        self.title = "TV Series"

    }
}
```

For some reason, the above script throws up an index out of range error, but if I switch

```
seriesDict["Title"] = "\(seriesData[0])"
seriesDict["SeriesID"] = "\(seriesData[1])"
seriesDict["ChannelName"] = "\(seriesData[2])"
```

to

```
seriesDict["Title"] = "\(seriesData[0])"
seriesDict["SeriesID"] = "\(seriesData[0])"
seriesDict["ChannelName"] = "\(seriesData[0])"
```

There is no error. I have been trying to figure out why I can't seem to access the second and third component of seriesData. After some debugging, I have noted that seriesData is structured as follows:

```
["Title1", "00000001", "Channel1"]
["Title2", "00000002", "Channel2"]
["Title3", "00000003", "Channel3"]
[...]
["Title99999999", "99999999", "Channel99999999"]
```

I am new to Xcode/Swift so any help would be much appreciated (along with an explanation for why the above is failing. Thanks!

Comment: I have it as `for i in 1..<readings.count` to skip over the first line. It seems the error was actually being thrown because the very last line of the file was an empty line. Trying to figure out how to fix that but that's not relevant to the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am gonna guess that your problem is that Xcode didn't add the "series.txt" file to your project's copy bundle resources. To do this click on the blue project icon in your navigation view on the left panel of the interface. (It should be at the top).[image]

(icon highlighted in blue).
After clicking that, go to Build Phases (the tab with blue lettering)[image]

And at the bottom of the view click **Copy Bundle Resources** then press the plus and add your **series.txt** file[image]

Doing this will add the **series.txt** file to the main bundle and thus make it accessible via `NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("series", ofType: "txt")`

Hope this help! :D

Comment: Thanks, though I had it added in properly haha. It seems the error was actually being thrown because the very last line of the file was an empty line. Trying to figure out how to fix that but that's not relevant to the above question.

Answer (score 0):

The error was being thrown up because the very last line of the file was a blank line. Trying to figure out how to not read that but that's a separate issue I think I'll be able to figure out.